# understanding forking - simple

Tags: c, multiprocessing, fork

if I have a program like this:

```
int i = 0;
int status;
bool result = true;

    for(i = 0; i < numfiles; i++) { // LOOP 1
        if (fork() == 0) {/* Child */
            if (substLines(s1, s2, filenames[i])) {
                exit(0);
            } else {
                exit(2);
            }
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < numfiles; i++) { // LOOP 2
        wait(&status);
        ....
    }

    return result;
}
```

I have the following question.

1. what happens if a child process exists, before the program even knows about the wait(). I guess my question is regarding how a program is 'read'. Again, for example.  If I exit from the first child, whilst still going through `LOOP 1`, what happens (does it even know about LOOP 2 at this point)?
2. is this a concurrent program? the parent seems to be waiting on the children after is forked them all, so i would say yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [man page of wait](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wait) says

> If a child has already changed state, then these calls return immediately.  Otherwise they block until either a child changes  state  or  a  signal  handler interrupts the call

so question1 doesn't matter

and question2, the answer is no.

Concurrency means they are running at the same time. It needs mutil-core CPU or more than one computer such as distributed system.

your program is multi-process, it is just Parallelism, which means they are running one by one under the schedule of CPU, for more info: [Scheduling_(computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing))

Comment: why doesn't question 1 matter? I dont really understand the definition of wait (i mean, i know it blocks the process till the child has returned). could you explain in simpler terms.

Comment: as @SzG says, when a process exited, it goes into a zombie state first. we call function wait is just to handle the zombie state of that process and clean up some resource the zombie process hold. So if your main process still in Loop 1, it doesn't matter, because all exited process are stay in zombie state. it is never too late to call wait

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to @simon_xia's excellent answer.

A killed or exited process becomes a `zombie` until its parent calls `wait` for it. And yes, this is the official terminology. :-) In zombie state everything is cleaned up (memory pages, open files, env, etc), just the exit status or killing signal number are kept.